# Is there any way to get the size of a remote file without downloading it?

Tags: macos, http

Is it at all possible to get the size of a remote file without downloading it? The file is over HTTP, not (S)FTP. I want to know this because I want to download something while connected with a limited 3G wireless plan and I don't want to use all my bandwidth in one pop. I have no access to the server, at all. So I can't do anything server-side. I am on Mac OS X. Solutions that make use of the command line are a plus, but not required.

By the way, the specific file I want information for is the MP3 download from [this website](http://thechangelog.com/post/2925096065/episode-0-4-6-yui-3-node-js-jslint-and-douglas-crockford).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by getting the `Content-Length` header, so long as it is HTTP.

One way of doing this on the command line is with `curl`, for example:

```
chris@chris-laptop:~$ curl -I -L http://www.fakkelbrigade.eu/chris/movies/drosovol1_final_h264_download.mp4
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Jan 2011 22:22:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Last-Modified: Tue, 11 Jan 2011 16:32:52 GMT
ETag: "3aa003-1b0c3479-49994a2c6f500"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 453784697
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

`Content-Length` is in bytes.

Comment: No problem! Glad you found a solution :)

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ There's also this addon that would help if you are a firefox user.

Answer (score 1):

You can issue `HTTP HEAD` requests to get the only header data. `Content-Length` is what you want.

```
$ telnet superuser.com 80
Trying 64.34.119.12...
Connected to superuser.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
HEAD / HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Length: 141
Location: http://stackexchange.com
Date: Tue, 25 Jan 2011 22:21:28 GMT
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the server is setup and the file. With most files the server sends it in the headers, but it may be a dynamic file and therefore it doesn't know (and your browser can't guess how long it will take.

tobylane$ telnet stackexchange.com 80

Trying 64.34.119.12...

Connected to stackexchange.com.

Escape character is '^]'.

GET /

HTTP/1.1 302 Found

Location: http://stackexchange.com

Date: Tue, 25 Jan 2011 22:01:22 GMT

Connection: close

I'm not sure what a good request is (GET / worked on other sites), but I hope this helps.

Comment: What "other sites" did it work for? It would be more helpful if you would post the ones it worked for instead of one it didn't work for.

Comment: Also, just a tip. You can indent code/console output like that by four spaces to make it preformatted and a lot more readable.